# Symfony2 Entity ManyToOne

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, entity

> Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a null variable in
>   messages\index.html.twig at line 11

**{{ message.author.name }}** -- is working

**{{ message.recipient.name }}** -- is doesn't and i don't know why everything is the same with author

TWIG:

```
Nadawca: {{ message.author.name }} {{ message.author.surname }}
Odbiorca: {{ message.recipient.name }} {{ message.recipient.surname }}
```

Controller:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $limit = 100;
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user_data = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Messages');
    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('m')->where('m.author = :authorid')
                                                 ->orWhere('m.recipient = :authorid')
                                                 ->setParameter('authorid', $user_data->getId())
                                                 ->getQuery();
    $messages = $query->getResult();
    return $this->render('messages/index.html.twig', array(
        'messages' => $messages,
        'user' => $user_data,
    ));
}
```

Entity User:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
private $surname;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Articles", mappedBy="author")
 */
private $articles;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Messages", mappedBy="author")
 */
private $messages_author;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Messages", mappedBy="recipient")
 */
private $messages_recipient;


public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->messages_recipient = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->messages_author = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->articles = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Entity Messages:

```
        /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=16777216)
 */
private $text;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"default" = 1})
 */
private $published;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
 */
private $date;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="messages_author")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $author;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="messages_recipient")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="recipient_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $recipient;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->date = new \DateTime("now");

}
```

Comment: Try to do a "{{ dump(message) }}" in your twig template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error would imply that there is no recipient present in one or more messages. Go over all messages that you are retrieving from the database and check if any of them have a recipient that is NULL. Or query the database real quick with a simple `SELECT * FROM message WHERE recipient_id IS NULL`.

This is due to lazy loading. At first both `author` and `recipient` in your Message entity are empty or Proxy objects. As soon as the property is accessed doctrine will attempt to load the associated User entities into the Message. So when you call `{{ message.recipient.name }}` and your `message.recipient` does not actually return a User entity it will stay NULL thus causing an error stating it can not access property `name` on NULL.

Comment: Ehh one message does not have an author id but null instead... code is ok

Comment: @PawełSuchodolski So I assume you got it working :) That's great, glad I could be of help.

Comment: Yeah i forgot that 1 inserted article does not have author_id in it O_o